# Turkish characters in TYPO3 RTE aren't possible at TYPO3 UTF-8 Installation?

Tags: unicode, character, typo3, rte, turkish

I want to insert a turkish name into my TYPO3 RichText-Editor (RTE, sysExt. `rtehtmlarea`), for example: "Özoğuz". The special letter "ğ" is here my problem, I've only see a question mark, after saving my text content element (s. pictures).

My charset is `UTF-8` (setup.ts) and the database is also utf-8

```
config.metaCharset = utf-8
```

I also tried to insert `&#287;` instead of "ğ" at code view (<>), but I've got the error, see second picture.

-
Maybe the turkish language needs ISO 8859-9 (Latin-5)?
**How can I allow turkish at my german TYPO3 Website?**

Backend:

[image: RTE backend TYPO3]
[image]

Frontend:

[image: Frontend]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTF-8 handles Turkish chars correctly, the DB error at save and later lack of Turkish special chars definitely indicates, that your DB or at least table or column doesn't use UTF-8, note that also for TYPO3 6.0+ it's required to create UTF-8 table yourself and `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['setDBinit'] = 'SET NAMES utf8;'` will be **ignored** ([read the notice](https://wiki.typo3.org/UTF-8_support#Issues_with_.24TYPO3_CONF_VARS.5B.27SYS.27.5D.5B.27setDBinit.27.5D)).

Make sure that your MySQL server is configured to work with UTF-8 by default and also convert wrong tables/fields to use it.

Comment: Hi, thanks, i will send it to my Administrator. I don't create the database at installation. Cheers!

Comment: The admin do the rest ...
`iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf8 dump.sql > dump-iconv.sql` great, thanks for your help.